# Single User: Turn off locking for Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, performance

I'm running an upgrade script against a database hosted in Microsoft SQL Server. It's taking a while. Some of the queries are not worth optimising any further, for various reasons.

I'm the only person using this database: Is there a way that I can tell SQL Server to not bother with transactions/locking?

For instance, on a DELETE ... WHERE, does SQL need to get exclusive locks on the rows it's about to delete? If so, can I tell it not to bother, since this is the only running query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [SQL Query Performance - Do you feel dirty? (Dirty Reads)](http://blogs.neudesic.com/blogs/phil_scott/archive/2005/12/05/11.aspx).

Edit: This is just speculation, but if you are the only connection to the SQL Server, you could get exclusive lock at the table level using `WITH (TABLOCKX)`. You are sacrificing concurrency, but it could get faster.

Comment: Useful, so I've upvoted, but the query I'm actually having problems with is a DELETE ... WHERE; I've expanded my question.

Comment: That's okay as the DELETE command allows you to use some table hints as well, so eed3si9n's WITH (TABLOCKX) will work.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off Autocommit (aka implicit transactions); you'll need to do a commit() at the end.  The log file will grow correspondingly large, be sure you've got enough disk space.
Is tempdb on the same disk?

Comment: This database and tempdb are both on the same 1TB volume (2x500GB, striped).